# inline if statement not working angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is minor but I cant for the life of me figure out what is going on... so

I have an inline if statement like so..

```
<button *ngIf="item?.fields?.assetType !== 'tool' || item?.fields?.assetType !== 'questions'">NEXT</button>
```

so basically the functionality is.. if the returned data has an `assetType` of `tool` or `questions` don't show the button.. now the behavior works when the data that gets returned has an `assetType` of `tool` the button is hidden but when I get data where the `assetType` is equal to `questions` the button still shows up..

here is the data that is being returned... as you can see `assetType` is equal to `questions` so.. the button should be hidden but it isnt

[image]

Im sure the problem is something small I just cant figure it out,
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: || means "or".

Comment: I walked through it in my response. Hope that helps!

Comment: Voting to close as; *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assetType "questions" in your example above, let's walk through it:

item?.fields?.assetType !== 'tool' **TRUE**

item?.fields?.assetType !== 'questions' **FALSE**

Statement would evaluate to **TRUE** since it's a logical OR.

Comment: Thank you! totally understand now.. for some reason I thought if I had put it has && it wouldnt work because one would always be false..